# How do you set GDB debug flag with cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have tried setting the debug flags using the

```
set
```

command in `cmake` but I cam unsure what to add. I have been told things like `DEBUG=true` but so far i am unable to find the correct flag to set.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you want to build for debug (including source information, i.e. -g) when compiling, use

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug <path>
```

If you want to build a release build, you can use

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo <path>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. When I try to run `gdb`, my backtraces consist entirely of memory addresses and question marks with no function names or anything.

Comment: set the path in the gdb if its not set to the source file directory by using below
gdb> directory "directory path"

Comment: you can use set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g") in CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use the CMAKE GUI to make this change. Doing `ccmake` with the project will yield a screen similar to this:

[image]

Entering *Debug* in the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` field will allow you to build with debug flags.

Comment: For a person new to using CMake, ccmake is an excellent solution. I'd suggest that `RelWithDebInfo` might be more helpful than `Debug` for the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE. It would also be good to mention that they should hit `g` to generate after editing. If you wanted to go the extra mile, you could include all the keystrokes (`/` to start searching `type` to find BUILD_TYPE, `Enter` to start editing the field...)