# How can you add warning flags using cmake cross platform?

Tags: cmake

I see a number of articles that suggest you check for compiler and add flags as appropriate, eg.

`if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
  ...
endif()
if (MSVC)
  ...
endif()`

This is a deeply undesirable situation though.

It relies on you having, for every project, to add specific support for each compiler that you support, one at a time.

Other things, like [C++11 features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984442/how-to-detect-c11-support-of-a-compiler-with-cmake/20165220#20165220) and [debug flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005982/how-do-you-set-gdb-debug-flag-with-cmake) are automatically generated by cmake for each of the compilers it supports.

Is there no equivalent solution for adding the equivalent of `-Wall` / `/W3` to the compile simply via a cmake setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It relies on you having, for every project, to add specific support for each >compiler that you support, one at a time.

At now you can only have something like `compiler.cmake`, where you configure suitable flags for each compiler, and share `compiler.cmake` among projects.

> Is there no equivalent solution for adding the equivalent of -Wall / /W3 to the >compile simply via a cmake setting?

No, now there is only disscussion about similar feature and it's possible implementation, see

https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2016-March/028107.html

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who finds this...

There is a reasonably robust implementation of this which can be found here, as a 3rd party addition:

https://github.com/ruslo/sugar/wiki/Cross-platform-warning-suppression

You use it like this:

```
## Project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(npp)

# Dependencies
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/npp)
... whatever ...

# Clone entire sugar repo to source folder and import
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sugar/cmake/Sugar)
include(sugar_generate_warning_flags)

# Generate flags, included excluded flags, etc.
# see: https://github.com/ruslo/leathers/wiki/List
sugar_generate_warning_flags(
  flags
  properties
  ENABLE ALL
  DISABLE c++98-compat padded
  TREAT_AS_ERROR ALL
  CLEAR_GLOBAL)

# Library / executable if any
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/npp/*.cpp)
add_library(npp STATIC ${SOURCES})

# Set flags
set_target_properties(npp PROPERTIES ${properties} COMPILE_OPTIONS "${flags}")

# Local tests
enable_testing()
add_executable(tests "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/tests.cpp")

# Set flags
set_target_properties(tests PROPERTIES ${properties} COMPILE_OPTIONS "${flags}")
target_link_libraries(tests npp)
add_test(tests tests)
```

Obviously this is far from ideal, as it's quite irritating to have to clone a set of modules, but it's practical for the moment.