# How to add C++ flag -Wno-unused-function on cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I added on my CMakeLists.txt on Android:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-error")
```

but I get multiple errors like this:

```
 error: unused function 'createParserError' [-Werror,-Wunused-function]
```

There's nothing that could rewrite `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you add warning flags using cmake cross platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255910/how-can-you-add-warning-flags-using-cmake-cross-platform)

Comment: "There's nothing that could rewrite `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`." - Please, do NOT **describe** what your code contains and what it doesn't contain. Instead, add your code into the question post, preferrably in form of [mcve]. The single line `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)` is definitely not enough to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With modern cmake, you can use `add_compile_options` and `target_compile_options` instead of setting the variable directly

Thus in your context you can write

```
add_compile_options(" -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-error")
```

to add the compile options to all targets or simply

```
target_compile_options(LIBRARY_NAME SCOPE "-Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-error")
```

to set those options for one target.
If you need it to be cross platform

```
if(${PLATFORM_1})
  add_compile_options("WARNING_FLAGS_FOR_PLATFORM1")
elseif(${PLATFORM_2})
  add_compile_options("WARNING_FLAGS_FOR_PLATFORM2")
endif()
```

replace the variable by your required values